# Get website to accept password using selenium using python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, firefox, passwords

I am trying to automate some things within parentvue using selenium in python.  It works when I try manually. When i get to the login page (https://va-pwcps-psv.edupoint.com/PXP2_Login_Parent.aspx?Logout=1&regenerateSessionId=True), I am using send_keys but getting an invalid username/password after hitting submit. I've tried with and without headless.

Note. The site does not allow me to use the saved password autofill. I have to type it in manually. With headless disabled I manually tried to enter the password when it popped up through selenium.  Didn't work.  Figured it could be a quirk so with headless enabled I setup try / excepts to look for items on the login page or the page after login.  it did not get past the login page. Is there a way around this issue? My code is pretty basic:

```
    options = Options()
    options.add_argument('--headless')
    options.binary_location = r'C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe'
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
    driver.get(parentvue_url)

    i_am_a_parent = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_MainContent_LoginIamParent"]')
    i_am_a_parent.click()

    user_name = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_MainContent_username"]').send_keys(site_name)
    time.sleep(1)
    password_box = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_MainContent_password"]' ).send_keys(site_password)
    login_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_MainContent_Submit1"]' )
    login_button.click()
```

Comment: The obvious answer is that `site_name` and/or `site_password` are incorrect.  Have you double-checked those values?

Comment: yes. I'm 100% sure those are correct. with headless disabled I manually tried to enter the password.  didn't work.  Figured it could be a quirk so with headless enabled I setup try / excepts to look for items on the login page or the page after login.  it did not get past the login page.

Comment: As a side comment, why are you using `find_element_by_xpath()` if you know the id?  Why not just search directly by the id?

Comment: I can use id. I've just never had an issue using xpath.  I'll read up to see if one is better than the other.

Answer (score 0):

```
import time

time.sleep(10)

options = Options() options.add_argument('--headless') options.binary_location = r'C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe' driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options) driver.get(parentvue_url)

i_am_a_parent = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_MainContent_LoginIamParent"]') i_am_a_parent.click()

user_name = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//[@id="ctl00_MainContent_username"]').send_keys(site_name) time.sleep(1) password_box = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//[@id="ctl00_MainContent_password"]' ).send_keys(site_password) login_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_MainContent_Submit1"]' ) login_button.click()
```

After entering the password, let the code run and set the wait accordingly.

Comment: thanks but still doesn't work. I can see name/ p-word getting injected when headless is off. I've printed the password to the terminal to ensure it's correct.  I think it might have something to do with the site's login form because I get invalid if I try to paste the pword in manually and hit login.

Comment: Please correct the code formatting. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks